# Java 8 Stream Api ошибка

Tags: java, java-stream, java-8

Проблема в том что [java](/questions/tagged/java) не видит переменную `p`.

```
public class Main {
    static Collection<Persone> peoples = Arrays.asList();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createModelInCollection(100);
        List<Persone> filtered =
                peoples
                    .stream()
                    .filter(p -->p.getName().startsWith("Ivan"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    static void createModelInCollection(int i) {
        Persone persone = new Persone();
        String[] name = { "Ivan", "Kola", "John", "Kate", "Nicole", "Tony",
                "Alex", "Brandi", "Megan", "Dima", "Frank", "Phil", "Kai", };
        String[] lastName = { "Stark", "Aniston", "Kross", "Green", "Akira",
                "Jemenson", "Freeman", "Stiffler", "Phinch", "Obama",
                "Sokolov", };
        for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
            persone.setAge(random(80));
            persone.setName(name[random(name.length)]);
            persone.setLastName(lastName[random(lastName.length)]);
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                persone.setGender("MAN");
            } else {
                persone.setGender("WOMAN");
            }
            peoples.add(persone);
        }

    }

    static int random(int i) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        return rand.nextInt(i);
    }
}
```

ошибка:
`Multiple markers at this line 
- p cannot be resolved 
- p cannot be resolved to a variable`

использую java 8. OS linux
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите разобраться в чем проблема.

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: Может явное приведение к типу поможет?

Comment: `Multiple markers at this line
 - p cannot be resolved
 - p cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: пример кода брал отсюда http://prologistic.com.ua/polnoe-rukovodstvo-po-java-8-stream.html

Comment: студию перезапускал?

Comment: У вас символ `-` какой-то не тот. `p -> p.getName().startsWith("Ivan")`
Попробуйте перепечатать эту строку.

Comment: @SeniorAutomator
я использую Eclipse.
перезапускал , не помогло(

Comment: @iksuy    `--`  перепечатал не помогло.
правда чучуть поменялась ошибка
`Multiple markers at this line
 - p cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - p cannot be resolved
 - p cannot be resolved to a 
  variable`

там помоему что то не так с переменной `p`

Comment: "p cannot be resolved to a variable" - сообщение IDE, а что говорит сам компилятор? Попробуйте скомпилировать с помощью javac.

Comment: File Menu → Project Structure → Project -> project lang level какой стоит?

Comment: people где определён? и зачем тут `.filter(p -->p.getName().startsWith("Ivan"))` два тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обновил Eclipse до последней версии все заработало)
проблема с переменной `p` ушла.
лишний минус убрал)

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в лишнем минусе/дефисе в `p -->p.getName().startsWith("Ivan")`

Замечу в скобках, что проблемы также с фактическим типом `peoples`, с работой метода `random`.